# Read xml from thecatapi

Tags: node.js

I try to get the url from their xml format but I couldn't do that. I want to get the url part and I tried different method but it seems that it is the closest to success:

```
parser.on('error', function (err) { console.log('Parser error', err); });

            https.get('https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml', function (resp) {

                resp.on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log('Error while reading', err);
                });

                resp.pipe(concat(function (buffer) {
                    var str = buffer.toString();
                    parser.parseString(str, function (err, result) {
                        var haha = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
                        console.log('Finished parsing:', err, haha.response.data.images.image.url);
                        // return message.util.send(`Requested by ${message.author}`, { files: [books] });
                    });
                }));

            });
```

But the problem is that I get error. I get this:

> Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

So hmm yeah. I don't know how to do that.
If I use this code with only JSON.stringify(result) then I get this:

```
Finished parsing: null {"response":{"data":[{"images":[{"image":[{"url":["https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get.php?id=aul"],"id":["aul"],"source_url":["http://thecatapi.com/?id=aul"]}]}]}]}}
```

So hmm I don't know how to get the **url** part. It is little difficult to me. Yeah I know it is json and I can read easier json format, but not this. I don't have any idea how to read the url part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from other website:

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=xml', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the respesult.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    let url = data.split("\n")[5].trim();
    url = url.substr(5, url.length - 11);
    console.log(url);
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```